# DataTable is not working fine but working when developer console is open

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using dataTable which is not working well.

I am getting this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-example - Ajax error. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

from the following code :

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable( {
             "scrollX": true,
     "ajax": {
         "url": "lognew",
         "dataSrc": "data"
     },
     "columns": [
         { "data": "id" },
        {"data":"requested_number"},
        {"data":"customer_reference"},
        {"data":"status"},
        {"data":"denomination"},
        {"data":"amount_paid"},
        {"data":"paid_currency"},
        {"data":"customer_logs"},
        {"data":"api_logs"},





        ]
   });
```

**But this is working fine when I enable the developer console and refresh the page**.

Please suggest.

Comment: What about adding - `"serverSide": true,` - option in your datatable declaration?

Comment: The json coming from `lognew` is not valid. Check in your dev tool.

Comment: then why it is working when i open developer tool

Answer (score 0):

probably because of your url, change your url to `/map where the file is/lognew` or try `/lognew`

Comment: why to /map ? why it was working when developer console is open

Comment: I had the same problem, it was working in dc but not on the website

Comment: an example: my programm name is lognew in the map test on the webserver, Then I change url to /test/lognew and then it worked for me

Comment: Do you publish your project to a map?

Comment: so you changed the url to map ?

Comment: Yes, i provided the full path

Comment: I have it like this: /projectmapwhereIpublish/nameofmapwherethiscodeis/getdata

Comment: What is the mapname where this file is in ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172248/discussion-between-ankita-kashyap-and-baas-b).